# Excel count number of dates (in rows) which fall under a predetermined period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i have been playing with Excel for a while, and one thing led to another, i wanted to try this: How would i calculate the instances of dates (such as below) in one sheet

[image: List of Names and Dates]

And count which of those dates fall under the 30/60/90 day period (such as below) I'm looking to see if i could have a final tally up the number of instances of dates which fall below 30/60/90 days to the current date in another sheet.

Using the table example gave that i would know that 2 dates fall under the 30/60 days period, and one fell under the 90 days period

[image: Tally List]

Is there a solution to my predicament?

Edit: More accurate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `IF()` function.

```
=IF(TODAY()-B2<=30,30,IF(TODAY()-B2<=60,60,IF(TODAY()-B2<=90,90,"Other period")))
```

Or try `IFS()` if you have ***Excel-365***.

```
=IFS(TODAY()-B2<=30,30,TODAY()-B2<=60,60,TODAY()-B2<=90,90)
```

Another option is-

```
=XLOOKUP(TODAY()-B2,{30,60,90},{30,60,90},"Other Period",1)
```

[image]

Comment: This almost hit the mark. I'm looking to see if i could have a final tally up the number of instances of dates which fall below 30/60/90 days to the current date. Using the table example gave that i would know that 2 dates fall under the 30/60 days period, and one fell under the 90 days period

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CEILING(D$6-B$2:B$6,30)=D2))
```